# How to convert a pandas dataframe to matrix format in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks as shown. (`df.to_dict()` is given at the end):

```
model   scenario    module      
AIM/CGE 2.0 ADVANCE_2020_1.5C-2100  wind_total_share    high    high
SSP1-19 wind_total_share    high    high
SSP2-19 wind_total_share    high    high
AIM/CGE 2.1 CD-LINKS_NPi2020_400    wind_total_share    high    high
TERL_15D_LowCarbonTransportPolicy   wind_total_share    medium  medium
TERL_15D_NoTransportPolicy  wind_total_share    medium  medium
GCAM 4.2    SSP1-19 wind_total_share    medium  medium
IMAGE 3.0.1 IMA15-AGInt wind_total_share    low low
IMA15-Def   wind_total_share    low low
IMA15-Eff   wind_total_share    low low
```

`model`, `scenario`, and `module` are indices while `Infrastructure` and `Investment` are two columns of the dataframe. I'd like to convert these two columns into the matrix format, where Infrastructure is similar to x-axis and Investment in similar to Y-axis. Furthermore, both in Infrastructure and Investment, I need to classify them into Low, Medium and High.
In the cells, I'd like to have the name of model and scenarios that satisfy the given category (low/medium/high) for given variable (Infrastructure of Investment) as shown in the screenshot below. There could also be cases when a scenario is high for Infrastructure, but low or medium for Investment and vice versa.
[image]

I also want to have another matrix, which shows the number of scenarios that fall into given cell. The second matrix matrices should look something as shown:
[image]

I am not familiar with getting such matrix format by modifying the existing pandas dataframe. Are there any functions, or module available that could be used for this purpose? How can I convert my dataframe to the matrix format as shown in the screenshots using Python?

`df.to_dict()` looks as follows:

```
{'Infrastructure': {('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2020_1.5C-2100',
   'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.0', 'SSP1-19', 'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.0', 'SSP2-19', 'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.1', 'CD-LINKS_NPi2020_400', 'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.1',
   'TERL_15D_LowCarbonTransportPolicy',
   'wind_total_share'): 'medium',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.1', 'TERL_15D_NoTransportPolicy', 'wind_total_share'): 'medium',
  ('GCAM 4.2', 'SSP1-19', 'wind_total_share'): 'medium',
  ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'IMA15-AGInt', 'wind_total_share'): 'low',
  ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'IMA15-Def', 'wind_total_share'): 'low',
  ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'IMA15-Eff', 'wind_total_share'): 'low'},
 'Investment': {('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2020_1.5C-2100',
   'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.0', 'SSP1-19', 'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.0', 'SSP2-19', 'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.1', 'CD-LINKS_NPi2020_400', 'wind_total_share'): 'high',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.1',
   'TERL_15D_LowCarbonTransportPolicy',
   'wind_total_share'): 'medium',
  ('AIM/CGE 2.1', 'TERL_15D_NoTransportPolicy', 'wind_total_share'): 'medium',
  ('GCAM 4.2', 'SSP1-19', 'wind_total_share'): 'medium',
  ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'IMA15-AGInt', 'wind_total_share'): 'low',
  ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'IMA15-Def', 'wind_total_share'): 'low',
  ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'IMA15-Eff', 'wind_total_share'): 'low'}}
```

Comment: A pandas question including reproducible input data... That alone deserves +1 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some brainstorming for a while and came up with the solution myself. It is long, but it looks like this.

First, I made the list of scenarios which are high, medium and low for both Infrastructure and Investment respectively:

```
infra_high = (df[df["Infrastructure"]=="high"].index.get_level_values(0) + " " + df[df["Infrastructure"]=="high"].index.get_level_values(1)).to_list()
infra_medium = (df[df["Infrastructure"]=="medium"].index.get_level_values(0) + " " + df[df["Infrastructure"]=="medium"].index.get_level_values(1)).to_list()
infra_low = (df[df["Infrastructure"]=="low"].index.get_level_values(0) + " " + df[df["Infrastructure"]=="low"].index.get_level_values(1)).to_list()

invest_high = (df[df["Investment"]=="high"].index.get_level_values(0) + " " + df[df["Investment"]=="high"].index.get_level_values(1)).to_list()
invest_medium = (df[df["Investment"]=="medium"].index.get_level_values(0) + " " + df[df["Investment"]=="medium"].index.get_level_values(1)).to_list()
invest_low = (df[df["Investment"]=="low"].index.get_level_values(0) + " " + df[df["Investment"]=="low"].index.get_level_values(1)).to_list()
```

Next, I did the intersection of the scenarios which are high, high; high, medium and high, low for Infrastructure and Investment as follows:

```
i1 = list(set(infra_high).intersection(set(invest_high)))
i2 = list(set(infra_high).intersection(set(invest_medium)))
i3 = list(set(infra_high).intersection(set(invest_low)))

i4 = list(set(infra_medium).intersection(set(invest_high)))
i5 = list(set(infra_medium).intersection(set(invest_medium)))
i6 = list(set(infra_medium).intersection(set(invest_low)))

i7 = list(set(infra_low).intersection(set(invest_high)))
i8 = list(set(infra_low).intersection(set(invest_medium)))
i9 = list(set(infra_low).intersection(set(invest_low)))
```

Next, using the Excel file, I recreated the matrix I wanted to make:
[image]

Then, I assigned the list for each cell of the dataframe as follows:

```
landing_zone1.loc["High","High"] = i1
landing_zone1.loc["High","Medium"] = i2
landing_zone1.loc["High","Low"] = i3

landing_zone1.loc["Medium","High"] = i4
landing_zone1.loc["Medium","Medium"] = i5
landing_zone1.loc["Medium","Low"] = i6

landing_zone1.loc["Low","High"] = i7
landing_zone1.loc["Low","Medium"] = i8
landing_zone1.loc["Low","Low"] = i9
```

And I did the same for matrix of number of scenarios using `len()` of each list.

Answer (score 3):

`pivot_table` could help here.

The 2nd matrix can be directly obtained with:

```
df.assign(values=1).pivot_table(values='values', index='Infrastructure',
          columns='Investment', aggfunc=sum)
```

which gives:

```
Investment      high  low  medium
Infrastructure                   
high             4.0  NaN     NaN
low              NaN  3.0     NaN
medium           NaN  NaN     3.0
```

For the first one, you could first reset the index to build the expected values:

```
temp = df.reset_index(2, drop=True).reset_index()
temp['value'] = temp['level_0'] + ' ' + temp['level_1']
df2 = temp.pivot_table(values = 'value', index='Infrastructure',
                       columns='Investment', aggfunc=list)
```

In `df2` multiple *identifiers* are grouped in a list. If you want them one per row, you can explode the dataframe:

```
df2.explode('high').explode('medium').explode('low')
```

to get

```
Investment                                    high                      low                                         medium
Infrastructure                                                                                                            
high            AIM/CGE 2.0 ADVANCE_2020_1.5C-2100                      NaN                                            NaN
high                           AIM/CGE 2.0 SSP1-19                      NaN                                            NaN
high                           AIM/CGE 2.0 SSP2-19                      NaN                                            NaN
high              AIM/CGE 2.1 CD-LINKS_NPi2020_400                      NaN                                            NaN
low                                            NaN  IMAGE 3.0.1 IMA15-AGInt                                            NaN
low                                            NaN    IMAGE 3.0.1 IMA15-Def                                            NaN
low                                            NaN    IMAGE 3.0.1 IMA15-Eff                                            NaN
medium                                         NaN                      NaN  AIM/CGE 2.1 TERL_15D_LowCarbonTransportPolicy
medium                                         NaN                      NaN         AIM/CGE 2.1 TERL_15D_NoTransportPolicy
medium                                         NaN                      NaN                               GCAM 4.2 SSP1-19
```